# Why the onStartLoading() calls on orientation change for api level >= 27?

Tags: android, api, android-lifecycle, loader

I have used initLoader() in my project to make an API call with the loaders and this will be started after calling forceLoad() in onStartLoading(). It is observed that on configuration change or whenever my fragment's onStart() is called it will call onStartLoading() due to which loader starts again which is not expected. It should call onLoadFinished() directly instead of loadInBackground(). This issue is occured only on API level >= 27.
I found that this is due to the support library changes in an andriid. Please help me to figure out how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Activity re-creates after orientation changes by default. So every method of Activity called again according to the Activity life cycle.

if you want to handle it kindly follow Android Guideline [Handle Configration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)